# How to change split-window-below to split-window-right?

Tags: window-splitting

I am using AucTeX with GNU Emacs 30.0.50. It has a shortcut `C-c C-l` for viewing the processing of the TeX file. It seems to be using `split-window-below` command for opening the new buffer. Is there any way with which I can change this behavior and always open the new buffer with `split-window-right` command? What should I put in my .emacs for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `split-window-below` behave like `split-window-right` each time you call `TeX-recenter-output-buffer` which is bound to `C-c C-l`:

```lisp
(advice-add 'TeX-recenter-output-buffer :around
            (lambda (fn &rest args)
              (let ((old-def (symbol-function 'split-window-below)))
                (fset 'split-window-below #'split-window-right)
                (unwind-protect
                    (apply fn args)
                  (fset 'split-window-below old-def)))))
```

You could put it in your `.emacs`.

---

See [13.11 Advising Emacs Lisp Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html).

---

Since `C-c C-l` is bound to the function `TeX-recenter-output-buffer`, the main job is to modify the behavior of that function.

What `advice-add` does is like a piece of *advice*: it adds some code to the definition of the function (by **wrapping** it in this case);

the `:around` keyword indicates that: when you invoke `TeX-recenter-output-buffer`, it will **be executed in the body of `advice-add`'s 3rd argument**.

You can think of what `(advice-add FUNCTION-A :around FUNCTION-B)` does as:

```lisp
You call FUNCTION-A with some arguments> (FUNCTION-A args...)
What Emacs Lisp actually does> (FUNCTION-B FUNCTION-A args...)
```

The original behavior is `split-window-below`, so `FUNCTION-B`'s job is to make the symbol `split-window-below` represent another function, i.e., `split-window-right`:

```lisp
;; Bind "split-window-below" to another function -- "split-window-right"
(fset 'split-window-below #'split-window-right)
```

But don't forget to restore `split-window-below`'s *original* binding after executing `TeX-recenter-output-buffer`:

```lisp
(fset 'split-window-below old-def)
```

where `old-def` means what `split-window-below` represented originally.

The `unwind-protect` form makes sure that the above piece of code will always be executed whatever happens (e.g., an error is signaled).

For more details, use `C-h f`.

Comment: Thanks, this works correctly, can you please explain briefly what we did with this code? I would like to understand how this worked out.

Comment: @Niranjan: No problem.  I'm washing up now, and I'll come back later to refine my answer by adding some comments to explain it.

Comment: Great! Please take your time and thanks again :-)

Comment: @Niranjan: Updated

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for explaining all the details.

Answer (score 1):

`C-h v split-window-preferred-function` - it is probably set to `split-window-sensibly` but you can change it to e.g. `split-window-right`:

```
(setq split-window-preferred-function #'split-window-right)
```

but that will *always* split to the right (given a choice), so it may or may not work for your purposes.

You can always advise the function that is bound to `C-c C-l` (I guess that's `TeX-recenter-output-buffer`) to let-bind `split-window-preferred-function` around it, so that only this function will be affected:

```el
(defun TeX-recenter-output-buffer-right (orig-fun &rest args)
  (let ((split-window-preferred-function #'split-window-right))
    (apply orig-fun args)))


(advice-add 'TeX-recenter-output-buffer :around #'TeX-recenter-output-buffer-right)
```

This will limit the effect to just this function. BTW, I *think* this is right but I have not tested it. If it causes problems, you can always remove the advice to get back to the previous state:

```el
(advice-remove 'TeX-recenter-output-buffer #'TeX-recenter-output-buffer-right)
```

See [Advising Emacs Lisp Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) in the Emacs Lisp Reference manual.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response, but your first code (the global one) opens the new buffer in a new window altogether, it doesn't create a buffer in the same window.

Comment: Second one too :(

Comment: The other answer seems to work well though...

Comment: I thought you *wanted* a new window: "... I can change this behavior and always open the new buffer with `split-window-right` command?" But in any case, *you* choose which answer to accept, so if the other answer works for you, accept that one!

Comment: Ah no no, actually I wanted a buffer with `split-window-right` command, I guess keeping the answer as it is can also be resourceful for people who actually want new windows instead of right-split ones. Maybe you can just add a line describing this difference.

Comment: If I understood what you mean I would, but I don't currently. So I'll take a look at the behavior and test it a bit as well (it *is* untested :-) ) and maybe add some explanations. But the important thing is that you got an answer that you are happy with!